# How to check whether my browser is IPv6 enabled?

Tags: internet, website, web, ipv6

Is there some way to check if I have access to websites through IPv6?

Comment: Was the version you're on released within the last ten years? If so, it almost certainly is. All operating systems have supported it for over ten years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an end-to-end test, you can use http://testmyipv6.com/ to check how you connect by default.  It also has [a link](http://v6.testmyipv6.com/) for testing whether you can connect via IPv6 at all.

Answer (score 0):

Run a script to listen for connections on port 80, then type `http://[::1]/` into your browser. (Not tested, and this only checkes that you browser and OS supports IPv6, your ISP still might not)

Comment: That's where http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling comes in.

Comment: Wikipedia says it's `localhost` (and that teredo is the `2001::/32` block)

Answer (score 0):

Without running any third party tools, or having an IPv6 ISP, it is hard to actually to test yourself.

The easiest (but not the best) way is simply to [look on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_IPv6_application_support) or the browser's homepage and see if it says it is compatible.

Short of this, I would do what David X said - either use a script/web server that is IPv6 compatible, then go to the IPv6 localhost - http://[::1]/ and see if you access the site.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one real easy way: Go to [www.ipv6.org/](http://www.ipv6.org/).  It'll say if you are using IPv6 and provide hints on how to get it working.

Another traditional test is [www.kame.net](http://www.kame.net). If you are using IPv6, you'll see animated turtle.

**EDIT** Whoops, I only read question body, not name and didn't see that OP is asking to see if browser has support.

Comment: All I get at the first page is a link to something that looks like Swedish.

Comment: Strange. The site seems to be down. Had a typo in second address too, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little free and useful tool to check if you are IPv6 ready: **[IPv6 Checker](http://ipv6checker.ipv4-to-ipv6.com/)**

> IPV6 Checker can check your IPV6 connection readiness in few seconds.
>   After the installation and without the need of online connections it
>   will check your computer status and it will display the check result
>   right on the main app interface.

[image]